# django 1.5 python set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

We would like to add **X-Content-Type-Options nosniff** .

We can't upgrade to newer django version (1.5), so we can't use the **SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF** because we don't have **SecurityMiddleware**.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security middleware came from [django-secure](https://github.com/carljm/django-secure/), so you could install that.

However, you really should upgrade Django. Django 1.5 is years out of date and insecure.